# What is the meaning of this symbol in modern list view?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

Does anyone knows what this symbol means in modern SharePoint list view? This is coming in Title column for few list items but not for all items.

[image]

Comment: I think its about tagging. This icon means unknow tag

Comment: Thanks MP, your comment helped me to go in right direction.

Comment: It's a tag that means required metadata is missing from that item (or contact).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This symbol is coming for items which have blank value for one of the Mandatory column in list.

This list was migrated from SP 2013 to SPO. It seems due to value mismatch at source at destination, the mandatory column remained blank for some of the items

Answer (score 0):

It is a Section Sign - used to refer to sections of a book or document, especially in a legal document. Sometimes it can be used instead of an asterisk, if an asterisk has already been used.